# I want to execute JSON_requestarray in my android app... but its not working

Tags: android, android-volley

I want to execute JSON_requestarray in my android app but its not working, here is the code:

[image: Code Snippet Image [Link][1]]

I want to extract the contents from the array which my PHP returns as a Json_encoded array.. but every time I run it returns null

Comment: Volley currently doesn't support POST method with JSONArray request. Try changing your method.POST to GET and log the response.toString() to see if the response is ok.

Comment: Please include the code as text in the post itself - don't just link to an image of it.

Answer (score 0):

JsonArrayRequest does not support POST method.

```
JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest("http://url", new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
            Log.d("response", jsonArray.toString());
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

        }
    });
```

If the log "response" isn't correct maybe the problem is your web service.

Comment: no it doent work .... i have to pass the Contact number the php where it will be queried against the database and then return the jason array ...

Comment: Its your web service then.